# Rewrite PHP code snippet with While,each,list may be with Foreach or a simpler way

Tags: php

I have following code snippet but i dont understand what its do, but i think there is easy way to write this code again with a simple foreach like below, is that correct ?

```
        $paypal_message="";
while( @list($key,$value) = @each($paypal_post_vars)) {
    $paypal_message .= $key.":\t".$value."\n";
    if($key!='custom'){
        $insert_sql.=" `".$key."`='".$value."' , ";     
    }
 }
```

I think rewrite it like this ? is it exactly the same ?

```
foreach($paypal_post_vars as $key=>$value ){

    $paypal_message .= $key.":\t".$value."\n";

    if($key!='custom'){
            $insert_sql.=" `".$key."`='".$value."' , ";     
        }

}
```

Comment: Did you try it and see?

Comment: if your not going to test your code give up your coding licence, you do have a *coding licence* don't you?

Comment: this is not about testing the code, i can see the same results but there may be a reason why official payapal IPN uses this other way, ie. better security , may be faster, ... that why ask, not like a dumb idiots who just think if you get the same output its all good..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is functionally identical code, if you look at [php site - control structures foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) have the explanation below

You may have noticed that the following are functionally identical:

```
<?php
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
reset($arr);
while (list(, $value) = each($arr)) {
    //     ^^ supressing key
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

The following are also functionally identical:

```
<?php
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
reset($arr);
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```